# Verifying in GSC through Yoast with HTML Tag

Tags: google-search-console, site-verification

Each time my team tries to verify using the HTML tag in the Yoast plugin, we receive a message saying that it can't be verified. Checking source code confirms that the tag is placed properly. After a few days, GSC seems to automatically verify using the same method, but never "clicks" immediately.

This leads me to suspect there is some sort of time delay for the verification, but I'm not sure. Is there something else causing the error/delay, or is there something I don't understand about the verification process that can help?

Comment: How exactly is the property verified? Through the Yoast plugin itself or manually through GSC?

Comment: Verification is manual through GSC. The Yoast plugin just provides a way to easily add the HTML tag in a Wordpress site.

Comment: I've never encountered a delay myself. It's usually "instant". Is the HTML page containing the tag accessible to Google at the time of verification? Are you using the correct Google account??

Comment: Yes, the code is present on the homepage, which is accessible to Google. I'm not sure what you might mean by the right Google account; unless you mean that we might have accidentally switched between accounts, but I don't believe this is the case. We log into an account, get the HTML tag, post it to the site (via Yoast), publish, and then click verify in GSC. Again, it will work eventually, but almost never immediately.